# Having admob or adsense makes apps commercial use?

Tags: licensing, admob

The app is free, but if it has ads, such as `AdMob`, does it make the app commercial? Or non-commercial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the ads change the non-commercial status. Giving it away for free makes the app non-commercial. However the advertising in the app is used in a commercial manor, so if you are submitting your app to some market place, even though you are giving it away for free I would say it's commercial. Technically people are paying for it by clicking or viewing the ads instead of paying for it up front. Why not just sell it for 99 cents?